# How to create this custom JSON layout using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to create this JSON layout using jbuilder:

```
   "entities" : {
       "users": {
         1: {name: 'abs', age: 44},
         2: {name: 'arms', age: 12},
         3: {name: 'legs', age: 34},
        }
    }
```

I have this so far:

```
json.entities do
  json.users @response.users do |user|
    json.(user, :id)
  end
end
```

But this is returning:

```
entities: {
 users: [
  {
    id: 1
   }
  ]
}
```

I need to make the key in "users" to be the user.id value, and then list the attributes.

Comment: JSON allows keys as strings only.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the hash you need. You'll have to call `.to_json` on it if you need the string.

```
hash = {users:{}}
@response.users.pluck(:id, :name, :age).each {|u| hash[:users][u[0]] = {name: u[1], age: u[2]}]}
# hash.to_json
```